# Javascript that I add to page dosnt seem to run

Tags: javascript

The thing I want to achieve is that on a specific page my module places a google map with markers on it.

Here is how i do it:

First I add this:

```
$setting = variable_get('locationUrl', '');

if (!empty($setting)) {
    $items[$setting] = array( 
        'title' => '', //page title
        'page callback' => 'page', // use the same name as your pagecallback 
        // 'access arguments' => array('access simple page'),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'), // temporarily use this
    );
}
```

That is for creating the page.

Then I add this:

```
function page(){
     drupal_add_js('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=AIzaSyDcl28Qcn9GTi02rRtQaLgVS4GWZbGcQ8E', 'external');

     $settings['myModule']['location'] = db_query('SELECT * FROM {locations}')->fetchAll();
     drupal_add_js($settings, 'setting');
     drupal_add_js('sites/all/modules/GoogleMapByDave/DGMap.js','external');

     $html = '
           <div id="map-wrapper" style="width:100%;height:500px;margin:auto">
           <ul id="map-list"></ul>
           <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:auto"></div>
           </div>
     ';
     return array('#markup' => $html);
}
```

That is for page content and adding the javascript.
I probbably should write this line differently right? "drupal_add_js('sites/all/modules/GoogleMapByDave/DGMap.js','external');"

And my javascript:

```
(function($) {
   Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
     attach: function(context, settings) {

      //var locations = Drupal.settings.myModule.locations;

      function initialize() {

           var mapOptions = {
               center: { lat: 56.9714744, lng: 24.1291624},
               zoom: 9
           };
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

           var locations = [
                    ['Mājas',56.956344, 24.197409],
                    ['Domina',56.966058, 24.162004]
                    ];

           for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

                  var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);

                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: loc,
                        map: map,
                        title: locations[i][0]
                        });
           };

       }

       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

     }
   }
)(jQuery);
```

I look at the page that is created by this. The gooogle maps api is placed in the page. And it seems the javascript is placed too, but it dosnt create google maps in the page.

I have found out that if i just add this to my code:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: 56.9714744, lng: 24.1291624},
      zoom: 9
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\'map-canvas\'),
        mapOptions);

    var locations = [
                    [\'Mājas\',56.956344, 24.197409],
                    [\'Domina\',56.966058, 24.162004]
                    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

      var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: loc,
        map: map,
        title: locations[i][0]
      });
    };

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, \'load\', initialize); });','inline');
```

This will make the map show, but then i cant pass down variables right?

Comment: You confirm that your `$html` is rendering properly?

Comment: Yes, the html is placed in correctly in the page. I opened up the page source and it was fine.

Comment: Also `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=AIzaSyDcl28Qcn9GTi02rRtQaLgVS4GWZbGcQ8E` is not a js. Have you tried this in your browser?

Comment: It is. Put it in your browser and you will see that it is.

Comment: It is not showing for me thats why I asked.

Comment: Interesting is that when i post a comment it seems that after the js part it takes away the question mark.. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDcl28Qcn9GTi02rRtQaLgVS4GWZbGcQ8E And it seeems now it didnt do that..